# to display the data of elements with pagination & 3 in each row with pagination in Datables

Tags: html, datatables

I'm stuck in an HTML & datatables.
The issue is I want to display elements such there are 3 elements in a row of a table & paginate them such that there are 30 elements in a table.
NOTE :- my data is dynamic & bound in a forEach loop.

here is my data

```
<tr><td>Delhi</td></tr>
<tr><td>Agra</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jaipur</td></tr>
<tr><td>Lucknow</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jodhpur</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bhopal</td></tr>
```

By default, they will be shown in 1 col & multiple rows.
But, I want them to be in  3 cols. 
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, can anybody help me plz!!
I'm stuck in this issue or if there is another option.